# Python a class method and defining a default value (if param is empty) and static method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been debugging `fix_keep_int_value_as_string` for hours now. I thought the proper way to send along a default value for a param was like this `def fix_keep_int_value_as_string(self, s='')`

Somehow the def method below is always outputting `s` as an empty string

**Why? And how do I correctly set a default param value (if not passed)**

```
class BaseShirtsSpider(Spider):
    # Strip numbers only, be aware! returns string
    @staticmethod
    def fix_keep_int_value_as_string(self, s=''):
        print(s)
        s = str(s)
        print(s)
        s = re.sub('[^0-9\-]','',s)
        print(s)
        return s   


class ChildBaseSpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    print(self.fix_keep_int_value_as_string(4))
    print(self.fix_keep_int_value_as_string("4"))
```

Comment: you have to instanciate your class and then call the methode 
for example : 
`
def YourClass :
   def fix_keep_int_value_as_string(self, s = ""):
      "your code"

obj = YourClass()
obj.fix_keep_int_value_as_string("4") this will call your function corretly 
try it

Comment: what is error or issue

Comment: updated code .. fix_keep_int_value_as_string is in class that is used as above. I always add self.method() but somehow now for the 1st time this is not working and s is always initiated to "" (empty) but there is also no error ...

is it explained here? I did change method to static ... https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Comment: the update doesn't make much difference, static method shouldn't take `self` as first arg, remove the `self`, from `fix_keep_int_value_as_string` and it will work

Comment: Did that and tried that. I am terribly missing something here ... now the error is
    `item['size'] = fix_keep_int_value_as_string(size)
NameError: name 'fix_keep_int_value_as_string' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Static method do not need a `self` argument. Currently you are trying to pass `'4'` into the `self` variable of `fix_keep_int_value_as_string` rather than the `s` variable.
2. The `self` variable in `ChildBaseSpider` does not exist until the class has been initialised (i.e. after `__init__` method has been called).

Assuming the `Spider` class does not take any arguments, the following will work:

```py
class BaseShirtsSpider(Spider):
    # Strip numbers only, be aware! returns string
    @staticmethod
    def fix_keep_int_value_as_string(s=''):
        print(s)
        s = str(s)
        print(s)
        s = re.sub('[^0-9\-]', '', s)
        print(s)
        return s


class ChildBaseSpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.fix_keep_int_value_as_string(4))
        print(self.fix_keep_int_value_as_string("4"))


ChildBaseSpider()
```

Comment: Thanks ... I think my confusion is that I would expect it somehow to work with `self` ... So "Static methods do not need a self argument." would read Do not work with self arguments ... maybe clear to many. Just not to me. Thx! Really appreciate this

Comment: It is kind of the point of static methods: they are not dependant on the instance (which is represented by `self`).